# How can I achieve compile-time encryption in C++ while maintaining runtime key security?

Tags: c++, encryption, constexpr, compile-time

I recently created an AES class in C++ that utilizes the `constexpr` feature to achieve compile-time encryption. Initially, I was excited about the idea of implementing encryption at compile time, but I've stumbled upon a concern. In order to initialize the AES class at compile time, I need to declare a `const` or `constexpr` array to hold the encryption key. However, this raises a significant issue: as the key is stored in a constant array, it becomes impossible to zero out the key during runtime or in the final executable. This implies that the key would be exposed to anyone who attempts to retrieve it (I might be wrong here?).

Considering this predicament, I'm curious to know if there is a way to maintain the benefits of compile-time encryption while ensuring the security of the encryption key at runtime. Are there any techniques or best practices that can help address this issue? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to achieve secure compile-time encryption in C++ or if it is even possible at the first place.

Comment: I think this is a question for a security based forum. Even scrambling keys in your executable is only going to slow attacks not prevent them from finding the key.

Comment: Encryption keys should never ever be hardcoded, so the whole idea is DOA.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with encryption? What kind of use case requires encrypted data in the final executable?

Comment: *"This implies that the key would be exposed"* Not necessary. constexpr *"inputs"* are not necessary in executable, constexpr variables are another story.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? Imagine you managed to solve your problem, and now have an executable containing a block of encrypted data but no key to go with it - what are you planning to do with all this?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik something like "the user can get the key somewhere then use it in the executable to retrieve the data"

Comment: @Jarod42 what do you mean by "constexpr inputs"?

Comment: In `constexpr auto v = foo("my_secret_key");`, input `"my_secret_key"` is not necessary in executable (as no longer needed, as it only here to compute `v`).

Comment: Do you have to trick the C++ compiler into doing the encryption? Just write a script that generates a source file with the encrypted data; run it as part of your build. This way you can manage your keys as you see fit.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, well, if we're going to state the obvious, I suppose I could've figured it out without even asking. I'm not completely clueless, you know. But hey, I was just curious if there's a chance to explore some alternative paths.